# Embedding text/html in an Object (instead of an iframe)

Tags: html, internet-explorer, iframe, cross-browser, cross-domain

```
<iframe data="/localfile.html" type="text/html" width="200" height="200"></iframe>
<iframe data="http://example.com/remotefile.html" type="text/html" width="200" height="200"></iframe>
<object data="/localfile.html" type="text/html" width="200" height="200"></object>
<object data="http://example.com/remotefile.html" type="text/html" width="200" height="200"></object>
```

Under every browser except IE, all 4 of these tests work. Under IE 6 and 7, the last one fails and shows an empty frame.
Is there a workaround that allows IE to load the external html in an object?

Comment: For IE8/9 also see question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8565409/embedding-text-html-in-an-object-in-ie8-9-instead-of-an-iframe-how

Comment: Do not use Object Instead of IFrame https://stackoverflow.com/questions/924946/use-of-iframe-or-object-tag-to-embed-web-pages-in-another

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Review the following for more information about how to use Object with IE: http://aplus.rs/web-dev/insert-html-page-into-another-html-page/

It boils down to a difference in what IE expects versus other browsers.  For IE, you have to use the classid attribute instead of the type attribute.  For example (from the above referenced site):

```
<!--[if IE]>
<object classid="clsid:25336920-03F9-11CF-8FD0-00AA00686F13" data="some.html">
    <p>backup content</p>
</object>
<![endif]-->

<!--[if !IE]> <-->
<object type="text/html" data="some.html">
    <p>backup content</p>
</object>
<!--> <![endif]-->
```

Note that the classid is specific to the content type that you are trying to server.

Comment: Chris' solution does not work in IE if you are trying to pull content from a remote server

Comment: The <object type="text/html"> works fine in IE8 (at least on my computer!).

Comment: @RealHowTo:  You might notice that both this question and answer were posted before IE8 was even available..