# Can I use OBJECT to embed remote content for IE?

Tags: html, object, internet-explorer

I am trying to use `OBJECT` to embed content from a remote server into a webpage. The remote content is a component provided by a third party and they host it on their domain. I have been able to get the `OBJECT` tag to "work" for all browsers using relative URL's for `data` (same domain) but IE fails completely any time the `data` attribute references a remote site.

Is there a way for me to get around this limitation? Is it something that can be fixed with a crossdomain.xml entry or some other flag that can be specified in the HTML?

---

I realize that `IFRAME` is a possible alternative solution to using an `OBJECT` but I would prefer to find out how to handle this with an `OBJECT` if possible. If it is not possible to do this with an `OBJECT` then I will know I have to look for other options.

---

Based on [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/924946/use-of-iframe-or-object-tag-to-embed-web-pages-in-another) I have decided that I will try to make this work with an `IFRAME` and not worry about `OBJECT` tags. If it ends up causing issues with the third party provider's software we can address it at that point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would placing it in an iframe work?

Comment: I would like to find out if there is a solution to this problem without resorting to using an iframe but I will do that if I am unable to find an object solution.

Answer (score 0):

This guy covers the topic pretty well if your looking for alternatives / workarounds.

[Objects Cross Domain](http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/asp.net/calling-cross-domain-web-services-in-ajax/)

Sounds like a proxy method on your webserver may be the way to go though if you really want it in an Object.