# How can I load a remote document into an IFRAME in Internet Explorer? (IE6, IE7, IE8)

Tags: iframe, cross-domain

I [posted a question the other day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1904325/can-i-use-object-to-embed-remote-content-for-ie) about why IE8 would not allow me to embed a page using the `OBJECT` tag. Per that discussion, and per my other research, I decided to just go with an `IFRAME` as it was not clear that the third-party application actually needed to be in an `OBJECT`.

Now here I am, a day later, finding out that IE8 has the same cross domain issue with `IFRAME` that it does with `OBJECT`. Is there any way around this? Why can I not find any discussion about this being an issue?

It has been awhile since I have had ot use an `IFRAME` for anything but I am pretty certain that this used to be really easy to do. Am I missing something, or am I really stuck going back to early AJAX days of having to build a local PHP proxy script to proxy my request to the remote server?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [EasyXDM](http://easyxdm.net/). It's a library which wraps cross-browser quirks and provides an easy-to-use API for communicating in client script between different domains using the best available mechanism for that browser. Caveat: you need to have control over both domains in order to make it work (where "control" means you can place static files on both of them).