# How can I load webpage content into a div on page load?

Tags: jquery, ajax

Without using iframes, is it possible to load the contents of

```
<div id="siteloader"></div>
```

With an external site e.g. somesitehere.com

When the page loads? - I know how to load contents from a file, but wasn't sure how to load a whole site?

Many thanks,

Comment: Iframe is better than object for loading html page https://stackoverflow.com/questions/924946/use-of-iframe-or-object-tag-to-embed-web-pages-in-another

Answer (score 52, accepted):

This is possible to do without an `iframe` specifically. jQuery is utilised since it's mentioned in the title.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Load remote content into object element</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="siteloader"></div>​
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $("#siteloader").html('<object data="http://tired.com/">');
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Note this will not work if the remote page’s [X-Frame-Options header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/X-Frame-Options) disallows it.

Answer (score 39):

Take a look into [jQuery's .load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function:

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('#siteloader').load('http://www.somesitehere.com');
    });
</script>
```

However, this only works on the same domain of the JS file.

Comment: This jQuery .load() method is better than the jQuery .get() proposed in other responses, because it allows you to load an specific item from the external url DOM (for example, just the content of a div and not the full page). That way you will avoid to have duplicated markup like two "body" and so:  $('#result').load('ajax/test.html #container');

Answer (score 12):

With jQuery, it is possible, however not using ajax.

```
function LoadPage(){
  $.get('http://a_site.com/a_page.html', function(data) {
    $('#siteloader').html(data);
  });
}
```

And then place `onload="LoadPage()"` in the body tag.

Although if you follow this route, a php version might be better:

```
echo htmlspecialchars(file_get_contents("some URL"));
```

Comment: Dont you think `$.get` is Ajax?

Comment: No, this is not possible in ajax, but it is possible in jQuery alone. a $.get() can be called once the page has loaded to dump the page into the specified div

Comment: Your example is using Ajax in jQuery. I think you are trying to explain something different than your example.

Comment: @Njdart: [`$.get`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) is a shorthand Ajax function.

Answer (score 1):

You can't inject content from another site (domain) using AJAX. The reason an iFrame is suited for these kinds of things is that you can specify the source to be from another domain.