# Load external div content to my page div

Tags: jquery, load, external

I am trying to load external website #external-div content to the page on #mydiv div. I have tried by attaching this jquery

`<script src="js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>`

and script is

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#mydiv').load('http://localhost/qa/ask #external-div');
    });
</script>
```

My div

`<div id="mydiv">loading...</div>`

I have downloaded jquery from here http://jquery.com/download/?rdfrom=http%3A%2F%2Fdocs.jquery.com%2Fmw%2Findex.php%3Ftitle%3DDownloading_jQuery%26redirect%3Dno

But its not loading anything.

Comment: Do you have some errors?

Comment: The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must to be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol.

Comment: I have added character set and now no error but still not loading content. Am I embedding right jquery?

Comment: Your script link is fine, assuming it's in the right place.  What's the space doing in the url in the load line?

Comment: show the http://localhost/qa/ask file

Comment: okay i have tried with removing space but still not loading `$('#mydiv').load('http://localhost/qa/ask#external-div');``

Comment: Now I checked and getting error like this `GET http://localhost/qa/ask 200 OK 106ms`

Comment: It is a form to submit question. Long file where I can place?

Comment: `$('#mydiv').load('localhost/qa/ask');`——can get anything？

Comment: I tried this and still not getting anything. Even I have tried with live/production website but still not loading anything.

Comment: try     $('#mydiv').load('http://localhost/qa/ask');——i miss http above     and     $('#mydiv').load('/qa/ask');——relative path

Comment: But my site is not on relative path. I am trying to create one script where my user can embed this div into them web page to load my question form and them user can submit question to my site from that div instead of come to my website

Comment: i think jquery.load() function is not surpported accessing cross-domain

Comment: Ah than how can I load it? can I fix frame with iframe and if I want to move page to little top in iframe is it possible?

Comment: Yes you are right it is not supporting cross domain. :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ajax/jQuery - Load webpage content into a div on page load?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9963799/ajax-jquery-load-webpage-content-into-a-div-on-page-load)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try code bellow to get callback respon:

```
$('#mydiv').load('http://localhost/qa/ask #external-div', function(response, status, xhr) {
    if (status == "error") {
        var msg = "Sorry but there was an error: ";
        alert(msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
      }
});
```

Comment: I have placed after my js and same error like `GET http://localhost/qa/ask 200 OK   108ms` but nothing loads