# How to load an external webpage into a div of a html page

Tags: jquery

I need to load a responsive website into a div in my HTML page without using an `iframe` element.

I have tried [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12938386/load-external-div-content-to-my-page-div); it's working for a single page URL, which I mentioned in the script.

```
$('#mydiv').load('http://localhost/qa/ask#external-div', function(response, status, xhr) {
    if (status == "error") {
        var msg = "Sorry but there was an error: ";
        alert(msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
      }
});
```

Comment: Do you have permission from the external website owners to do this? Framing another site within your own is "frowned upon" (if not a blatant breach of copyright).

Comment: I have tried to display external website into my webpage div using jquery.but its working for a singe page of the external website.i need to display the entire external website(all pages) within a div in my webpage.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I load a webpage inside a div using Javascript without IFRAME and JQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15211969/how-do-i-load-a-webpage-inside-a-div-using-javascript-without-iframe-and-jquery)

Comment: There is no need of permission because i am trying to display one of my own webpage into a div of my another html webpage

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ajax/jQuery - Load webpage content into a div on page load?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9963799/ajax-jquery-load-webpage-content-into-a-div-on-page-load)

Comment: interesting that  `$(function(){ $("#includedContent").load("blah.html"); });` or with http://server/blah.html,  doesn't work when server is other than the current one.

Comment: Should you use iframe? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/924946/use-of-iframe-or-object-tag-to-embed-web-pages-in-another

Answer (score 133):

Using simple html,

```
 <div> 
    <object type="text/html" data="http://validator.w3.org/" width="800px" height="600px" style="overflow:auto;border:5px ridge blue">
    </object>
 </div>
```

Or jquery,

```
<script>
        $("#mydiv")
            .html('<object data="http://your-website-domain"/>');
</script>
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SsJsL/)**

Comment: If i used like this i am getting the scroll bar like we are getting while implementing iframe inside a div.can u tell some other way to display a website in a html page

Comment: You can hide the scrollbars if you like.

Comment: add `overflow:hidden` to the iframe or obeject.

Comment: I am implementing this object tag with in a responsive website so i cant able to specify widht,height and also i cant use overflow:hidden.it will be better if you suggest some other solution instead of using object

Comment: mwell, you are using jquery, right ?... `$("#myContainer").css("overflow","hidden");`

Comment: @OptimusPrime, no It was a repply to user2089987. He said he can't modify the css. He can if he uses jquery or javascript...

Comment: @TCHdvlp  yes he can. but doesn't seem to work here, check http://jsfiddle.net/SsJsL/60/

Comment: @Optimus Prime , yes it does work (FF 27.0), dunno how your view is, but the scrollbar you see is the one from the fiddle HTML element.If look at the first fiddle you see 2 scrollbars.Or do i misinterpreter  wrong?

Comment: @OptimusPrime if i want to load just part of the page lets say the div with class `.the_class_i_want` not the whole webpage?

Comment: @indago https://www.google.co.in/search?q=how+to+load+only+part+of+a+page+in+iframe&oq=load+only+part+of+page+in&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l2.5781j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8 try these links.

Comment: @user2089987 does this answer not solve your problem?

Comment: Thank you for this post. It is exactly what i am looking for but in my case the 800*600 window is empty. does anyone know why this might be? I am using the div on my homeserver.

Comment: @Embed101 why don't you share a fiddle? or ask a new question. More people would be able to help.

Comment: Superb Answer... Appreciate this

Comment: why do some websites like google.com or youtube don't show using the `object` tag?

Comment: Load denied by X-Frame-Options: https://system.netsuite.com/pages/customerlogin.jsp?country=US does not permit cross-origin framing.

Comment: Can someone tell me how to access the elements of the HTML loaded in object tag?
Eg: Fetching text input value using jQuery 
`$('#username').val();`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42267945/how-to-access-the-elements-of-the-html-loaded-in-object-tag

Comment: The jQuery example in the linked JSFiddle demo doesn't work.  At least, not in the version of Chrome I'm using.  YMMV.  The browser console contains the message, `Refused to frame 'https://system.netsuite.com/' because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 'self'".`  
  
However, the simple HTML example does work.  That may be fine for anyone who needs to load a page from a static URL.

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned in this stackoverflow thread,
[difference between iframe, embed and object elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16660559/difference-between-iframe-embed-and-object-elements)

You can use <embed> tag, instead of <object> tag. If you require communication between child and parent.

> † As pointed out in the comments below; scripts in <object> will run but the parent and child contexts can't communicate directly. With <embed> you can get the context of the child from the parent and vice versa. This means they you can use scripts in the parent to manipulate the child etc. That part is not possible with <object> or <iframe> where you would have to set up some other mechanism instead, such as the JavaScript postMessage API.

```
<embed type="text/html" src="snippet.html" width="500" height="200">
```