# Put Phonegap InAppBrowser into div

Tags: cordova, inappbrowser

Is it possible? 
I need it to show jQuery Mobile footer and header under and above InAppBrowser.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you have to use InAppBrowser? Because I doubt you will be able to do that without some heavy customization. Have you tried/taken a look at a solution like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18145353/2281093)?

Comment: You can use iFrame instead

Comment: @VickyGonsalves Thanks for suggestion, I've tried both <iframe> and <object>, but <iframe> crashes app =/ http://stackoverflow.com/q/20093412/1548085 and <object> is just not displayed http://stackoverflow.com/q/20076090/1548085

Comment: @AndrewLively Thanks for suggestion, I've tried it, but <object> is just not displayed http://stackoverflow.com/q/20076090/1548085

Comment: Some sites (like Facebook), don't allow iframes, so that isn't a solution.

Comment: @janot did you find an answer to this ? I'm looking for this solution. thanks

Comment: @Gredgebrick nope

Answer (score 1):

You can add header and footer from css by inserting css. Recently changed background in inAppBrowser. Please have a look on this [Link](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.7.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html#insertCSS)

Comment: Thank you, as I understand it can be only non-interactive footer and header (without buttons)?

Comment: Yes. Non interactive header and footer can be added.

Comment: @janot hi did you achieve jQuery Mobile footer and header under and above InAppBrowser. With interactive header?

Comment: @NijilNair is it possible inAppBrowser with jQuery Mobile interactive header?

Comment: @NijilNair is there any other way to solve this? Possibly adjusting height of inappbrowser?

Answer (score 0):

Try using Iframe

> header code here

```
  <iframe class="iframe" id ="iframe" src="https://www.google.com"></iframe>
```

> footer code here