# "object" tag not displayed on Android

Tags: android, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova, android-webview

I have Jquery mobile Phonegap app and I'm trying:

```
<object type="text/html" data="http://validator.w3.org/"></object>
```

It works in desktop browsers but nothing is shown on Android device/emulator.

Comment: What about an iframe?

Comment: @Lesleh Thanks for suggestion, I've tried iframe but it's not working too (maybe because of same reason as here) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20093412/iframe-error-on-phonegap-android