# Displaying Magento cart externally is somewhat working

Tags: php, html, magento, cart

So I'm trying to get my front-end static website to work with Magento backend. 
(I'm not that great at php)

My setup:

www.mywebsite.com/shop2 <-Magento

www.mywebsite.com/index.php <-Static front end

I have a file located at www.mywebsite.com/test.php that correctly displays the contents of my magento cart using the following code:

```
<?php

require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/shop2/app/Mage.php');

$app = Mage::app();
$session = Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name'=>'frontend'));

$block = $app
->getLayout()
->getBlockSingleton('checkout/cart_sidebar')
->setTemplate('checkout/cart/sidebar.phtml');

echo $block->toHtml();

?>
```

However, when I insert the above code into my www.mywebsite.com/index.php sidebar area, it doesn't update with the cart contents of the website.

Any ideas why this would work in the test.php and not in my main index.php website?

Comment: What does it do?  PHP error?  Renders a cart with no items?  Does your code finish execution? etc.

Comment: Hi Alan! it renders the cart with no items, even though the test.php running at the same folder level shows the cart items.

Answer (score 0):

Making two PHP application communicate with one another, or making one run in the context of the other, is never a straight forward process. My first guess on this would be the application your `index.php` bootstraps (even if it's just a simple framework for your webpage) initializes session storage **before** Magento has the opportunity to.

Then, when you bootstrap your Magento environment

```
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/shop2/app/Mage.php');
```

The PHP sessions have already been started.  This means a Magento sessions never loads, and the user session is how Magento persists the cart information.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Alan. I've added <?php
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/shop/app/Mage.php');
session_start();
?> to the top of the page, above the <head> statement. Beyond this, is there anything I can do?

Comment: @user2487746 Beyond the scope of what I can help remotely with in a Stack Exchange answer.  You might try stopping the session before restarting it, or the session might not be working for some other reason.

Comment: Thank, I'll think it over

Answer (score 0):

I was able to import the test.php file which has my cart information using the following. For my purposes, it works alright now.

[How to load an external webpage into a div of a html page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18145273/how-to-load-an-external-website-into-a-div-of-a-html-page)