# How to open a website within a particular Div in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I want it to open a website within a particular `<div>` tag, just like in the following link: [Responsive](http://responsinator.com/). What am I doing wrong?

```
<html>
<head>
  <script>
   function mobile320()
    {
     window.location.assign("http://www.idevtechnolabs.com")
    }
  </script>

<style type="text/css">
 body{
  margin: 0px auto;
  padding: 0px;
  background: #06855a;
  text-align: center;
 }

.browser1{
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 320px !important;
  height: 480px !important;
  background: #efefef;
 }
</style>
</head>

 <body>
   <input type="button" value="Load new document" onclick="mobile360()" />
   <div class="browser1"> </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe

Comment: Put the title of your post into Google, you'll see many results. Have you tried anything at all?

Comment: It's better to post you code instead a screenshot of your code :)

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18145273/how-to-load-an-external-website-into-a-div-of-a-html-page

Comment: @F.Geraerts Fixed. Yikes! Not making a habit of that...

Comment: @TusharGupta :Thanks bro your answer meeet my requirement.. All of using iFrame is helpfull to do this

Comment: @F.Geraerts : Thanks there was problem to put code so I adds screen shot

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Change your function to this:

```
function mobile320() {
    document.querySelector(".browser1").setAttribute("src", "http://www.idevtechnolabs.com");
}
```

...and your div to this...

```
<iframe class="browser1"></iframe>
```

[Here's a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/CCqv5/).

Answer (score 3):

That's not a div, it's an iframe:

```
<iframe src="http://www.google.com"></iframe>
```

Comment: +1 even this one won't work, using google as source ;)

Comment: true, it would work only on google itself :)

Answer (score 2):

put an iframe element in the div and navigate to the desired website,

or do an http get request and set the inner html of the desired div to the response string u get.