# Embedding an HTML page into another

Tags: jquery, html, iframe

I am trying to include the source of a webpage within another. The embedded webpage has its own doctype, head and body declarations, and could have separate styles.

The trick here is that I wish to avoid an iframe, since I have the source available on the server-side, but not as an HTML page (I retrieve it from database).

I guess one way would be to create a page that would render it and then show it inside an iframe, but I aim at having one single page, though I did not find a way. Does anybody have a better suggestion?

I use jQuery in my application, so if I missed a solution there, this would be an option too.

Comment: Please post your code in www.jsfiddle.net or www.codepen.io or update your question with the code you tried so far.

Comment: Why have a separate page ? Just dynamically populate a div ?

Comment: @SulthanAllaudeen : I did not try anything yet, I am looking for the way to do it. But if you want the main idea, here it is:http://jsfiddle.net/xgsq4/

Comment: @user2515563 : see the jsfiddle: populating a div is... just _wrong_. Plus, styles come conflicting. I need something more evolved.

Answer (score 1):

If your server supports php, you can retrieve the page code from database with php and then echo it

Comment: This would produce something like the jsfiddle I produced for another user: http://jsfiddle.net/xgsq4/
Styles conflict, and I cannot think of an <html> tag somewhere inside the <body> tag as being clean.

Comment: you can fetch the code in an array, and then strip the start and the end of the code so <html> and </html> tags would be gone

Answer (score 1):

You shall use this one.

```
<html>
<head>
something here 
</head
<body>

<?php
require ('page1.html');
?>
```

Here is your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xgsq4/2/)

Answer (score 0):

There was a similar post asking ["How to load an external website into a div of a html page"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18145273/how-to-load-an-external-website-into-a-div-of-a-html-page)

Although i dont fully understand your situation. If you just want a dynamic page with no reloads, populating a div or other element from a data source would be much more efficient.

Heres another link on embedding webpages...
http://www.web-source.net/embedding_web_pages.htm

But like is said I dont understand your end goal fully, so maybe you should reword your question.

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

Reviewing my past questions and ignorance, I have the beginning of an answer for people who may be facing a similar situation:

Using [jQuery's .load()](https://api.jquery.com/load/) allows you to load a page or a portion of it and insert it into the current DOM.

```
$('#my-target-element').('/the/page/to/load.html')
```

This function strips the `<head>` and `<body>` tags but all their contents is preserved (including the `<head>`'s `<meta>` and `<link>`.

If you wish to load only a part of the remote page into the current one, you can use a jQuery selector, as in the example below:

```
$('#my-target-ol').('/the/page/to/load.html #my-included-list li')
```