# How can I view a part of an other website on my website?

Tags: html, css, web-deployment, visual-web-developer

I want to show a specific part of an external website on my website.

[image: specific part of an external website]

How do I do this? 
Can this action be illegal in some way?

**no embed available on this website. It looks pretty old too.

Comment: I think you need this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18145273/how-to-load-an-external-website-into-a-div-of-a-html-page

Comment: @Onovar he wants to grab a specific element from that page, not necessarily the whole page.

Comment: Ok, I tested this and it's working good. How do I make it auto scroll to the exact place I want to view?  
@Onovar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<div id="ab"><iframe src="//hodekar.tk"></iframe></div>`
and this css
`#ab {
display : block;
overflow : hidden}
iframe{
margin: -50px -60px}`
use minus margin so it will goes in that div and unuseful content will not be displayed in webpage. specify height of div and iframe

Comment: Ok, I tested this and it's working good. How do I make it auto scroll to the exact place I want to view?

Comment: Thank You, 
I Played with it a little bit and understood! :)

Answer (score 1):

im not sure if u can do that.. der may be a few privacy issue.. But u can show a different page in you webpage by using the iframe tag.
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp
Or HTML 5 supposrt video tags.. So if you can download the video u can display it using the video tags..
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp

Comment: Ok, I tested this and it's working good. How do I make it auto scroll to the exact place I want to view?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using iframes. This HTML element can embed another document from another page, but it also acts as other page.

Simple targetting with the selectors does not seem to be a solution.
But you could use iframe to load the page and than extract part of it with jQuery.

I think this should work for you:

```
video = $("your_frame_selector").contents().find("selector_of_the_DOM_element")
```

Comment: Please try adding an explanation of how to use them, why they might be helpful, etc. We don't like answers that are simply links to external sites as those links can possibly die. Sample code would be nice. Please note he doesn't want to simply show another website from his, he wants a specific element from another website on his.

Comment: possible to show specific section of website using iframe ?

Comment: I have tried and, unfortunately, it looks like not.

Comment: Hello @ondObno, 
Can you explain? :)

Comment: I made it much easier :) 
Check my own answer to the post

Comment: Yes, nice. But could it be used like that if you don't know what is the actual position of an element?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simplest way to do this: 
http://jsfiddle.net/hAtul/vk9avk7e/

Thank you guys :) !

CSS:

> ```
>   #ab {
>       display : block;
>       overflow : hidden;
>       width: 724px;
>       height: 391px;
> ```
>
> }
>   iframe {
>             height: 387px;
>             width: 641px;
>             margin-left: -42px;         }

HTML:

```
<div id="ab">
    <iframe src="http://www.mycampage.com/webcamtelaviv#player" scrolling="no" onload="javascript:jumpScroll()"></iframe>
</div>
```