# How to display a ( ASP.NET ) web application within a div?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

i have several web applications made in ASP.NET . Now, I 'm developing a web application (also in ASP.NET ) from where I can see my other applications. So I want to put in a div another Web application. How I do it ?

Thanks!

Comment: I didn't get your requirement exactly, but may be you can find all of your web application in IIS if you have setup them.

Comment: Could you use an iFrame for this? I *think* that might be what you're after, but your question is not very clear.

Comment: @mituw16 yes, it is that i want, tanks

Comment: You can do it in DIV also. Refer [this article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18145273/how-to-load-an-external-webpage-into-a-div-of-a-html-page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an `iFrame` to accomplish this task.