# Open another page inside main content div using 'Open in new tab...'

Tags: javascript, html, css

When the link is click on main content using "open link in new tab..." option , I want to load the page inside main content with sidebar and header.
Please see image below on what it should look like.

Thanks in advance.

[image: Before]
**Page before link was click.**

[image: After]
**Page after link was clicked.**

See [Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bumbumpaw/7Lj8ym6k/1/)

```
 <a target="_blank" href="https://jsfiddle.net/bumbumpaw/2e16m0c4/">This should load href value in main content w/ Sidebar,Header and Footer</a>
```

Comment: check http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to load an external webpage into a div of a html page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18145273/how-to-load-an-external-webpage-into-a-div-of-a-html-page)

Comment: @Aschab can you give me example please

Comment: You either redirect or you dont. You said you want to redirect, then redirect and have some modules with views, if you dont want redirect there are 3 perfectly valid answers.

Comment: Those answers just load another page in div using click event, but when I right click and "Open in new tab..." It opens the page in full page and without the header and sidebar(only the white area).

Answer (score 0):

I think you must look [jquery load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) . It will load html content from another link and append to html element via ajax .

for example

```
$( "#result" ).load( "ajax/test.html", function() {
  alert( "Load was performed." );
});
```

Comment: Thanks but I need to redirect to new page but still sidebar and header exist on the page when I click "Open in new tab."..

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the contents of #contents with an iframe, if you want to load external pages. 
[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7Lj8ym6k/2/)

```
    $("a").on('click', function(ev)  {
    ev.preventDefault();
    $('#content').html("<iframe src='http://www.w3schools.com'></iframe>");});
```

Comment: Thanks but I need to redirect to new page but still sidebar and header exist on the page when I click "Open in new tab."..