# how to access the elements of the HTML loaded in object tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-object

Eg: Fetching text input value using jQuery `$('#username').val();`

I had tried this from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18145273/how-to-load-an-external-webpage-into-a-div-of-a-html-page) question

Here is my code

```
<div id="siteloader"></div>

$(window).load(function(){
    $("#siteloader").html('<object data="http://testk.shopnix.org/admin" />');
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log($("#lemail_id"));
      $("#lemail_id").val("lemail_id");
      console.log($("#lemail_id").val());
    }, 10000)

})
```

[JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eot1me5s/) here

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Use event **onload** instead of timeout.
2. For access to object internal structure use method **contents()**
3. **WARNING:** It may doesn't work on jsfiddle. This site block XSS requests for security reasons.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="siteloader">
  <object id="object1" data="" />
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$(function() {
  $("#object1").load(function() {
    $(this).contents().find("#lemail_id").val("lemail_id")
  });
  $("#object1").attr('data', 'http://testk.shopnix.org/admin');
});
```

[js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eot1me5s/5/)

Comment: @KiranReddy I've written about it above, please be carefully

Comment: Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property from 'HTMLObjectElement': Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost" from accessing a cross-origin frame.