# Access externally loaded .html table cells with JS but without webserver

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

i have a html template which uses js. I am trying to load an external .html file which contains a table into that html template with js.
I am not running this stuff on a webserver.

In the html i have

```
<div id="table_placeholder">Load table heree</div>
```

I tried the following in my js:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
     //load the html file
     document.getElementById("table_placeholder").innerHTML='<object type="text/html" data="Export.html" ></object>';
     //access the loaded table
     var title_column_1 = document.getElementById("data").rows[0].cells.item(0).innerHTML;
     alert(title_column_1 );
});
```

The table in the Export.html has the ID "data"

When the able is loaded the html looks like this:
[image: loaded html]

But i am getting: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'rows' of null

I guess that i cannot access the html table i loaded with .innerHTML within the same js. Is there any way how could i achieve that? Or did i oversee something? Is it a problem with the order of loading all the stuff?

Comment: The issue is, that the file you load inside the `object` has its own `document`. You likely need something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42267945/how-to-access-the-elements-of-the-html-loaded-in-object-tag).

Comment: thanks i will have a look at it

Comment: Sadly no success, still getting the same error. Any other tips?

Comment: Could it be true that this is not possible because i not using a webserver?