# Content in one float from ref in another float

Tags: html, css

My html page is divided in to three columns using CSS and float.  In the left hand column I want to put a selection of links ... how can I direct these links to open in the middle (main) float?

code is from https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_template2_float with the difference that I've separated the style sheet from the html using

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css">
```

to tie the two files together.

As to what I've tried ... nothing.  The w3s link doesn't appear to have anything appropriate I could put in to the YYYY part of the link.

Comment: show your code and what you tried so far

Comment: You want external webpages to be opened within the boundaries of your middle column ?

Comment: why not use your layout as a template, make a new page for each link?

Comment: @Trunk I want a daily blog, where I have a calendar (of links) in column 1 which open up the posts of whatever day in column 2 (the middle column)

Comment: @moatist - ok.  I can see that would work ... I thought there might be some sort of target attribute.  If not - solved.  thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18145273/how-to-load-an-external-webpage-into-a-div-of-a-html-page

Comment: @user1945827 not unless you use iFrames like Trunk suggested.  If you can use server-side code (PHP, Perl) even better.

Comment: will go with @moatist suggestion but this means re-writing all previous files on a daily basis to reflect change in the calendar.

Comment: @user1945827 when using lots of pages you'll find it more convenient to solve it using server-side code, or JavaScript.  I'm not sure what you're familiar with.

Comment: thanks all ... you've shown me a couple of paths to follow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(".links a").on("click", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(".content #myIframe").attr("src", $(this).attr("href"));
});
```

```css
div { width: 49%; display: inline-block; }
.content { border: 1px solid #ccc; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="links">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="http://exocraft.io">exocraft.io</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://slither.io">slither.io</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://www.bing.com">bing.com</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <iframe id="myIframe" src=""></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: this is modified from what MajiD posted, now its working

Answer (score 0):

do this

```js
$(".links a").on("click", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(".content #myIframe").attr("src", $(this).attr("href"));
});
```

```css
div { width: 49%; display: inline-block; }
.content { border: 1px solid #ccc; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="links">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="https://www.google.com">google</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://www.yahoo.com">yahoo</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://www.microsoft.com">microsoft</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <iframe id="myIframe" src=""></iframe>
</div>
```