# is it possible to set up a webview in React pwa application

Tags: reactjs, webview, react-router, progressive-web-apps

The questions may seem confusing so let me clear it up a bit, imagine this, we have a header that when the user clicks on it, it takes the user to previous Route, so what I'm trying to do is basically this, each time a user clicks on a tab, for example, `buy Plane ticket` it takes the user to that `url` which is not a route inside the `pwa app` but, we still want that header to be there, so for example when the user clicks on it, it takes the user to the previous Route;
what I have basically done is set up a simple `a` tag with the `href` of that `url`

```
///something like this

<a href="somewhere">Buy plane Ticket</a>
```

Comment: Maybe this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18145273/how-to-load-an-external-webpage-into-a-div-of-a-html-page