# Add class when Load content from external source

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Given Script load data from specific div of external source on click. Now trying to add div class when loading content like image and text. I mean when contents loads new classes will auto added with `<div class="images"> img</div>` and `<div class="summery"> text text text</div>`

**HTML:**

```
<button class='btn'/>
<div id="load-here"></div> <!-- Load Here -->

</body>
```

**Script:**

```
$(function() {
    var page = null;
    var counter = 0;

    function getNext() {
    // Grab the next element from the array of date-outer divs and copy it to the .content div
        if (counter >= page.length)
            return;
        var elm = $(page[counter]).clone();
        elm.find('script').remove(); // Remove script tags in the div
        elm.appendTo('#load-here');
        counter++;
    }

    $('button.btn').click(function(e) {
        if (page === null) {
            page = false; // Prevents the request from being made twice
            $.get('http://test-html-site.blogspot.com/search/label/', function(data) {
                page = $(data).find('article.post.hentry');
                getNext();
            });
        } else if (page !== false) {
            getNext();
        }
    });
});
```

**HTML Structure of external site:** Given script load `.date-outer` per click. Means it load data form external site/link on click.

```
<body>
<div class="blog-posts hfeed"> 

<div class="date-outer">
Contecnt 1: img, text </div>

<div class="date-outer">
Contecnt 2: img, text </div>

<div class="date-outer">
Contecnt 3: img, text </div>

</div>
</body>
```

My question is when data loading, want to add custom class to image and text using given script. This is the [example site](http://test-html-site.blogspot.com/).

Comment: Might work for you. https://stackoverflow.com/a/12938543/3002273