# Show html from a link in a <div> on the same page

Tags: php, xhtml

I have created 2 div tags. In one of the div tags I'm having link and I want to display the result into another tag.

My code is:

```
<div>
  <div id="loginDiv"><a href="login.php">LogIn</a></div>
  <div id="loginPageDiv"></div>
</div>
```

How can I display my login page in "loginPageDiv"?

Comment: sounds more like you'd want an iframe. either way, your question is unclear, vague, and going to be closed.

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9963799/ajax-jquery-load-webpage-content-into-a-div-on-page-load

Comment: It's more of a question now that his code is showing up

Answer (score 2):

try using ajax. --> http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

for example

```
$('#loginDiv a').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: this.href,

  }).done(function( html ) {
    $("#loginPageDiv").append(html);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use java Script (Ajax call) to acheive this

and inside ajax call you set your result to that div id

```
document.getElementById("loginPageDiv").innerHTML = result
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('#loginDiv a').click(function() {
            $.get(this.href, function(data) {
                $('#loginPageDiv').html(data);
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```