# Multiple index files on front page

Tags: html, indexing

Is it possible to load different index file on front page and still look like default site name in browser, i.e. www.mysite.com for index.html and  www.mysite.com for index2.html ?

Comment: yes. using .htaccess file

Comment: When you say "front page", do you mean you are using [MS FrontPage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_FrontPage) on the server or do you just mean the "first page".

Comment: I mean my website index.html that loads first. I need another index2.html file that will load when triggered (by a button from another page) but the browser to look the same www.mysite.com and not www.mysite.com/index2.html. How can be done with .htaccess file ?

Comment: I managed to add this rule in .htaccess  'DirectoryIndex index.html index2.html'  But I need to add a link on my site that will load index2.html while the browser will show mysite.com alone. How to do that?

Comment: try find about 'mod_rewrite', hopely useful

Comment: The OP wants **both** files to be displayed under the the pathless domain, so .htaccess or mod_rewrite will not help.  The only way is to load the content dynamically using AJAX.  Or if it was 1994 you would use a frame!

Answer (score 0):

You can use AJAX to load content from your index2.html

for more info [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp)

Comment: While the browser will still show www.mysite.com as I want it ? or mysite.com/index.html  because I don't need that.

Comment: i mean try to load whatever content in your index2.html to index.html through AJAX request.

Comment: Actually I need to add one link in my site that will load www.mysite.com/index2.html but I dont want index2.html to be shown in browser url.

Comment: Isn't easier to add some rule in .htaccess like when people acces mysite.com/index2.html to show mysite.com alone but with index2.html content?

Comment: Have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9963799/ajax-jquery-load-webpage-content-into-a-div-on-page-load) for how to easily load in the content from another page into the current page.