# How to display a proper page in a div using ajax?

Tags: ajax, html, jquery

I tried to load a page (of same domain) using ajax. But it's showing only the static html part. Styling and js actions are not there. How to load the exact page in a div using ajax?

Comment: please share your code

Comment: This is exactly what an iframe is for, isn't it? A browser can't expect a html tag in a html tag, with all its dependencies in a head.

Comment: Reading about fancybox may help.

Comment: CSS should work but any javascript won't run, you need to call a function when the ajax call is complete to start off any scripts

Comment: @ppeterka66 so, is it like, it's not possible to display a proper page inside a div?

Comment: @Adam css is also not working :(

Comment: Unless you do the plumbing required to it, with say jQuery, as in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9963799/ajax-jquery-load-webpage-content-into-a-div-on-page-load), but I have not used this, so can't say for sure all the CSS and javascript will be in place... ([this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16193294/1667004) says CSS will be OK, but not JS)

Comment: Loading HTML page in the div tag will not work. Better you go for iframe (HTML 5 feature) and load the content of the iframe using ajax/jquery.

Comment: You'll need to show us some of your code, trying making a working example on http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @Adam actually there are a lot of files... so not really able to show the code in jsfiddle. Can u gv me ur email id? I can mail u all the files

Comment: @Optimus the problem is, I have a next button in the framework, on clicking the next page should be shown. If I use iframe, then ther's a little time gap between the click and the next iframe load. I don't want that