# how to get content of div in a html from another html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two html file

```
a.html
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>  
  </head>
  <body> 
    <div id="content">
        hello every one
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

and another page

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>  
  </head>
  <body> 
    <div id="result">

    </div>
    <iframe id="ifr" src="http://example.com/a.html">
    </iframe>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        divv = $('#ifr').contents().find('div#content').clone();
        $('#result').html(divv.html());
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

In second one I try to get first html and get contet div in it.after that I put this value to result div . 
but It's not work. How can I do that.

Comment: Are you permitted to use the `iframe` source? Any access origin errors/warnings?

Comment: not error not warning and I have permission

Comment: Are the two pages on the same domain?

Comment: No one of the in another domain.

Comment: You should have said that from the word go. When you say 'I have two html file' you're saying they are on your server ---- same domain. So that's a LIE.

Comment: Duplicate [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9963799/ajax-jquery-load-webpage-content-into-a-div-on-page-load](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9963799/ajax-jquery-load-webpage-content-into-a-div-on-page-load)

Comment: I'm sorry but I have two template page on the same domain, and I want to use second one from first one, so the second one must be render to ready for use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to use an iframe; you can use ajax to do that. It's very straight forward.

```
$(function() {
    $('#result').load('a.html #content',function()
        $(this).html( $('#content').html() );
    });
});
```

**EDIT**

As evident from comments below, scope of question has changed. The two pages are on different domains without `CORS`. Therefore the above answer would not work.

In order to use `ajax`, you may want to create a server-side script to act as a proxy. Then you'll call that script on your server and it will fetch the `a.html` page for you.

Comment: That's because you're trying to retrieve a page from another domain. To use ajax, the two pages have to be on the same domain or the source server has to allow the destination server to get pages from it. That's why it's important to give enough information. :)

Comment: I have two template page on the same domain, and I want to use second one from first one, so the second one must be render to ready for use.

Comment: Not sure I fully understand your question ... a two template page?!! What's that? If you have two pages on same domain, you can use the code I provided.

Comment: I believe `django` would have been a useful tag to include with your question, even though I doubt it would make a difference considering the code you've provided.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that could be the right way.

```
var ifr = document.querySelector('#ifr');
var html = ifr.contentDocument.querySelector('div#content').innerHTML;
$('#result').html(html);
```

Comment: I've just read about cross-domains.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6170925/get-dom-content-of-cross-domain-iframe