# Dynamically load index.html in Phonegap Application

Tags: javascript, html, cordova

I am beginner to phonegap. I want to create layout inside index.html which is driven by javascript and also having cordova to use apis in app. I am able to run hard coded index.html but I want to run as a live site inside phonegap and also want to use cordova plugins inside my live site.

Can anybody help me or any idea to how I use live site or dynamic html through javascript?

Thanks in advance,

Vijay Barnwal

Comment: Your question is extremely unclear.

Comment: Actually I want to add all the js,css files in index.html dynamically through javascript, I want to load my live site inside phonegap using just like window.location and also I can use all plugins of cordova inside my site.

Answer (score 2):

You can load a live website by any of these 3 methods:

1. Embed an HTML iframe `<iframe src="http://example.com"></iframe>`, for this to work, you will need to enable Cross-Origin Resource Sharing on your device and on your web server. Read [Cordova 3.5.0 Whitelist Guide](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.5.0/guide_appdev_whitelist_index.md.html#Whitelist%20Guide) and for server, [I want to add CORS support to my server](http://enable-cors.org/server.html).
2. Use metatag to redirect the user to the desired URL. 
   `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://example.com/" />`
3. If you still need to use all the Cordova functions and plugins, the only way to do it is by loading the website using AJAX into a `<div>` tag. Read: [Ajax/jQuery - Load webpage content into a div on page load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9963799/ajax-jquery-load-webpage-content-into-a-div-on-page-load) *Note: You still need to enable CORS for this to work.*