# Creating a website without refreshing at every link

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to develop a website that runs everything in the same file, but I don't know how do I search study materials for it.

Like that:

Normal website -> I'm on `index.php`. When I click on the menu "Contact", for example, it refreshes and load the file `contact.php`

Website that I'm trying to do -> I'm on `index.php`. When I click on the menu "Contact", the website makes an animation (fade, side-scroll, etc) and shows the content of Contact, without loading any other files.

Can anybody help me? I've worked with single page websites before, but all of then follows the One Page Scroll Website Model.

I believe that I need to work with AJAX, but I'm not certain yet.

Comment: Are you talking about single page applications? Try looking up angularjs

Comment: What you're looking for is called a "single-page" website and, yes, it's going to be almost 100% AJAX.

Comment: I would like to know why someone sent this question a -1...

Comment: @jpklzm because question can easily be researched on the web and your question is too broad and shows lack of research effort

Comment: I've made the same question on Brazilian stack and got the answer. I pretty good and explained answer, and I hasn't changed even a comma of it. Thanks them for don't be such ignorant people and try to help some users to find a way to solve their problems. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/6626/3511

Comment: @jpklzm, yes, I'm sure the reason they didn't flag your question is because they "don't be such ignorant people".  Why even bother to come here, since you got your answer on the Brazilian site?

Comment: I'm just making a research on the stacks. A cultural research, and I sadly lost a bet saying that the international stack would be better than the others. But on the others I received a lot of attention on my question and received pretty good answers. Here I only received attentions from the low rep guys who are trying to help and get helped. The "programming ninjas" just send a lower vote. It's a sad result...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to use a frontend MVC like:

- https://angularjs.org/
- http://backbonejs.org/

This will let you create seperate views, and do the AJAX loading for you.

Answer (score 0):

AJAX is your friend indeed. Just load another page into the div (or other element) u want to change.

[Ajax/jQuery - Load webpage content into a div on page load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9963799/ajax-jquery-load-webpage-content-into-a-div-on-page-load)