# How do I load a webpage inside a div using Javascript without IFRAME?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to load an external webpage into a div. I don't want to use an iFrame. And I want this done with plain Javascript or Jquery. I'm not sure how to go about it.

Comment: Better can use ajax function check it out

Comment: @Chanukya Varma use $.load function in jquery. http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: [Ajax/jQuery - Load webpage content into a div on page load?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9963799/ajax-jquery-load-webpage-content-into-a-div-on-page-load)

Comment: Actually I have embed code of my site ,if i copy embed code and  i paste it into another site  it is working with iframe but i want this happen using pure javascript or jquery not with iframe

Comment: I have used my embed code like this <div id="#My-page" style="width:900px; height:900px; position: absolute;overflow-x:hidden !important;-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch !important;">
<script>
$("#My-page").load("http://profiletor.com");
</script>
</div> but it is not loading the page

Answer (score 0):

```
$( "#DIVID" ).load( "Path" );
```

it will load your html data into any div.

Comment: I have used my embed code like this <div id="#My-page" style="width:900px; height:900px; position: absolute;overflow-x:hidden !important;-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch !important;"> <script> $("#My-page").load("profiletor.com"); </script> </div> but it is not loading the page

Comment: You can't load page out of Your project until the owner of that webpage enabled 'CROSS SCRIPTING' in his page.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways, here are a couple:

---

## .load()

### References

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_load.asp

http://api.jquery.com/load/

### Example

```
$( "#result" ).load( "ajax/test.html" );
```

---

## jQuery.ajax()

### References

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

## Example

```
$.ajax({
  url: "test.html",
  context: document.body
}).done(function() {
  $( this ).addClass( "done" );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem is easily solved using  `<jsp:include>` tag. But I wouldn't like to recommend. It just attach another JSP file to template.

**template.jsp**

```
<div id="HSpace">
    <jsp:include page="Header.jsp" flush="true" />
</div>

<div id="MSpace">
    <jsp:include page="Main.jsp" flush="true" />
</div>

<div id="TSpace">
    <jsp:include page="Tail.jsp" flush="true" />
</div>
```