# bootstrap - left menu link click to open a new page within a div section

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

Ref: http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/simple-sidebar/

From the above sample, on clicking the left menu link I would like to load a new page in the body section and also want to maintain the left menu navigation.

i.e on href link click I want to load a new page within the .

Thanks

**Update:-**
Each left navigation links loads a different html file and these different contents to be displayed in the main section accordingly.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9963799/ajax-jquery-load-webpage-content-into-a-div-on-page-load

Comment: Do you have separate html pages?

Comment: @Jay Did you resolve the issue? If so, can you explain how?

Answer (score 0):

I already did what I think you want. So, you can use a list. Each element of your list refers to a different div. 
For exemple, here is my code :

```
<div class="tabs" id="tabs">
     <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">One</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Two</a></li>
     </ul>


<div id="tabs-1">
        <?php include('Page1.php');?>
    </div>

    <div id="tabs-2">
        <?php include('page2.php');?>
    </div>
</div>
```