# Should I use <object> or <iframe> for loading a video?

Tags: php, object, iframe, youtube

I load lots of Youtube videos in one page (up to 25). Should I use iframe for each video or show it just in `<object>`? As I understand, if I use iframe, my page will load much faster, because it will load my page first and it will not have to wait to load videos. Am I right?

Comment: Opposite question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/924946/use-of-iframe-or-object-tag-to-embed-web-pages-in-another

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your understanding is incorrect. Your "page" (that is, your HTML document itself) will load and render in the same amount of time. However using `<iframes>` means the browser has to load not just the same video files that it would with `<object>`, but also the HTML contained within each iframe.

Note that YouTube instructs users to use `<iframe>` to embed a video because it allows YouTube to customize the HTML sent to the user: appropriate browsers will be given the HTML5 `<video>` treatment.

So it's a trade-off: you can slightly decrease page load times with `<object>` or `<video>` at the cost of excluding non-Flash (or non-HTML5 browsers, respectively), or you can use `<iframe>` and be sure of compatibility with whatever browser your visitors might be using.

Comment: Accessibility wise though, object tags (from my understanding) are much, much better to have. So that is another consideration as well.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `<iframe>` since `<object>` is deprecated. The first one supports both Flash and HTML5 video. The second one support only Flash. This is extremely useful for users who don't or can't use flash (all of iPad/iPhone users, some of Linux folks).

[Google Help on this question](http://support.google.com/youtube/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=171780&expand=UseOldEmbedCode#oldcode)

Comment: Object is deprecated? Source please!

Comment: @pst, http://support.google.com/youtube/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=171780&expand=UseOldEmbedCode#oldcode I mean deprecated for use with YouTube.

Comment: To be fair, `<object clsid="">` is also deprecated (not to be confused with the W3C-approved `<object type="" />`).