# OBJECT and IFRAME tag to embed html pages on same domain

Tags: object, iframe, tags, seo, integration

I have researched this question in numerous places, but I cannot find a definitive answer.
The question in detail is:
I want to import other pages from the SAME domain into EITHER an IFRAME or OBJECT TAG.
It's an html5 website, but I want the OBJECT or IFRAME tag to be searchable and not mess with SEO.
Which one do I use and why? 
Which one will work better for IE 6?

basically, (and it pains me to admit) I want to find a way to have one navigation bar that import into one of these tags so i do not need to change them on every page.

There is this stackoverflow question here: [Use of Iframe or Object tag to embed web pages in another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/924946/use-of-iframe-or-object-tag-to-embed-web-pages-in-another)

BUT it's much older and seems to dismiss html5

I'm trying to avoid:
Server side includes and
JavaScript dependency

Help is GREATLY appreciated!