# What is the best option for embedding content

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I'm screen scraping some news websites and echo(php) them in iframe or object. I do this because I am loading the complete website and in order to get it as "clean" as possible I put it in iframe or object. I have come to a point in where I have to decide whether to use iframe or object from now on.

So my question is: what is the best option when I echo content. I also run Jquery from the parent document on to the embedded content. What is better suited for this, the iframe or the object? So far I haven''t encountered problems but I would really like to know which one is "better" on the long run.

Comment: Most common is the MVC framework, where you have a View file such as a template that holds all the static content usually as HTML, with PHP variables for dynamic content. This allows a clear separation between code and display so you don't have to have giant messy echo's everywhere.

Comment: @MatthewMcGovern: I don't think that's what the OP is getting at.

Comment: @MatthewMcGovern way over my head:)

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Oh yeah, I made a huge assumption when I skipped the first line :P

Comment: assumption is deadly ;)

Comment: What is wrong with my question..?

Comment: @Youss: asking which of two options is “better” is a bit vague and debate-y. It’s not obviously amenable to a definitive answer. Personally I think your question as a whole is fine (because you’ve clearly defined your purposes), but the last sentence might make it sound vaguer than it is. (Of course, you’ve also mentioned that you’re basically hotlinking other sites’ content in iframes, which some people might think is unethical.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- An `object` tag is for media elements like flash, video, music.
- An `Iframe` tag is for embedding a website/application into a frame.

**Object vs Iframe**

> The [IFRAME element](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/#the-iframe-element) is part of the [upcoming HTML5 standard](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/). Also, HTML5
>   is developed by the major browser vendors out there (Mozilla, Opera,
>   Safari, IE), that basically makes a guarantee that we will have an
>   IFRAME element in the foreseeable future. Some of them have support
>   for some HTML5 elements already, like AUDIO and VIDEO and some new
>   JavaScript APIs.
>
> It's also [true that the OBJECT element](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/#the-object-element) is in the draft, but that's
>   because IFRAME and OBJECT will have different purposes. IFRAMES are
>   mainly designed for sandboxing web applications.
>
> So, my advise is to use IFRAME instead of OBJECT.

From [Use of Iframe or Object tag to embed web pages in another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/924946/use-of-iframe-or-object-tag-to-embed-web-pages-in-another)

Comment: What kind of problems do you think I will encounter in the future when using object instead?

Comment: You will use a tag for something its not made for. So not all browsers will support it if its even work at all. Becasue an `object` tag wil never parse html.

Comment: I have been able to make it work in all big browsers and as far as I can see there is now problem in html source code. It parses "data" in this case the data is html

Comment: You are right, I update my answer with a little exploitation

Comment: Thank you twice one for the link:)

Answer (score 1):

You should `iframes` because they are used everywhere and there are loads of adavantages to use them. Couple of my perspectives are as follows:-

- They run on portable devices. (That's why YouTube and Vimeo run on
  `iframes`)
- They have lots of useful plugins for safety. E.g.,
  [adsafe](http://www.adsafe.org/) to name a few.
- JavaScript/jQuery can be used easily with iframes. (it is really
  easy)

Comment: Thank you very much:) Good point on safety, I already knew that but I don't know anything about object "security"