# Client Side Includes on HTML pages

Tags: html, seo, include, accessibility, security

Previously, I had thought that the only way to get content from external URLs into your page, were to use an IFRAME or JavaScript to include it into your pages.

I've just learned of another way using the  tag:

`<object type="text/html" frameborder="0" data="http://Server/URL/"></object>`

I have found some content online that confirms this ability, but it doesn't talk much about features such as Accessibility and SEO of the page.

UPDATE:  I'm not looking for information on HOW to use this method, looking for information regarding what happens to my page when i use this method, such as:

- Accessibility: will screenreaders still be able read my document as if the content was included via a server side include.
- SEO: will google still be able to index this content?
- JavaScript: I have seen some of the articles talk about still being able to use JS like this, but are there any security implications.

The bottom line, this is not a well know method, so there's not much available online (that I can find anyway), so I'm looking to see if anyone has had experience implementing this method.   Thanks!

Comment: Is that even widely supported by current browsers? From what I know the `object` tag was often misinterpreted or ignored in the past...

Comment: Interesting. Re IE compatibility: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/311433/embedding-text-html-in-an-object-instead-of-an-iframe

Comment: Thanks for the info, I'll review that a bit more, hopefully get some more feedback on my question too.

Comment: I believe that the page to be included needs to be on the same server.

Comment: @RealHowTo from what I've seen, this is dependent on the browser, and that IE may have some issues pulling content from an external server, however, other browsers are able to do it just fine.

Answer (score 1):

I think the question linked in Pekka's comment should satisfy you.
Nonetheless you could consider XML data islands too.

Comment: pekka's answer gives me specifics of how to use it, which I admit, are more specific than I knew before.  But i'm not asking how to use this method, i'm asking about the impact of using this method to your page (Accessibility, SEO, javascript). Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To screen readers, object elements are [conditional content](http://www.w3.org/WAI/UA/implementation/eval_win_jaws402.html#conditional-content), so they are not rendered automatically and must have a [fallback](http://www.felgall.com/noiframe.htm).

For SEO purposes, the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/objects.html#edef-OBJECT) says the object can be activated by clicking on some highlighted text, for example.

```
<P><OBJECT declare
        id="earth.declaration" 
        data="TheEarth.mpeg" 
        type="application/mpeg">
   The <STRONG>Earth</STRONG> as seen from space.
</OBJECT>
...later in the document...
<P>A neat <A href="#earth.declaration"> animation of The Earth!</A>
```

Object elements have the same security restrictions as iframes, so cross-domain JavaScript is not allowed, but [exceptions](http://www.cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=cve-2010-0255) have been found and fixed.

**References**

- [HTML 4.0 Appendix B, Section 4: Notes on helping search engines index your Web site](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/appendix/notes.html#h-B.4)