# Placing a google ad breaks my css

Tags: html, css, layout

I had a page with the right-side layout like this one:

http://www.comehike.com/hikes/search_hiking_groups.php?redirect=yes&radius=&postal_code=

Where you can see the right side have 2 spots: the yellow buttons and the links below.

What I am trying to do is place a google ad on that page.  But the way I am doing it breaks the page.  Here is an example how it is messing up the right side css:

http://www.comehike.com/hikes/search_hikes.php?redirect=yes&radius=&postal_code=

What am I doing to mess up the css?  And how can I fix it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sidebar has a fixed height, so doesn't expand to contain the new content:

```
.what_to_do {
    height: 210px;
}
```

Remove it.

Comment: Actually, just changed the value there, but it didn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: Just remove it. You have a separate rule enforcing a min-height of 375px elsewhere anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting it in an iframe instead. That should encapsulate the ad in its own little window which can have independent css rules.

Comment: Or in an `object` if you don't want to use an IFrame: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/311433/embedding-text-html-in-an-object-instead-of-an-iframe

Comment: Many have speculated that placing addwords in a iframe violates their TOS. Also, google targets the adds based on the scraping the content of the page they are on. Ads on Iframe == no content == Irrelevent adds.  http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/AdSense/thread?tid=23c6139b3524dbaa&hl=en

Comment: Yeah I would like to avoid iframe.  I think the problem is with the html/css rather than the ad.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the side bar is using class `.what_to_do`, which contains the rule `height:210px`

I would recommend: instead of setting a fixed height, clear the bottom elements if they are floating, and let it naturally be the default of `height:auto;`. This lets the sidebar column expand to its contents.

Comment: `height` is `auto` by default - no need to specify it.

Comment: @eric, you speak truth. Edited