# css for html that is included via object

Tags: css, html

I have an html file that I'm "including" via object:

```
<object type="text/html" data="try.html">
</object>
```

I'd like to use CSS to control how the contents look, but the CSS code seems to be ignored for the HTML in the object. If I pull in pieces directly the CSS works so I know it's "right". If I look at the HTML with a debugger, I can see there's another BODY & HTML tag, but since I'm using an ID I figured it would still find it.

Any suggestions ?

**EDIT**

so I got this to work using the jquery with $.get() like this :

```
<div id="here">
</div>
 <script>
  $.get("try.html", function(data) {
  $('#here').html(data);
  });
</script>
```

but I'd still like to know why, the CSS didn't apply to the HTML code included by the object tag. I haven't found a good explanation of that yet.

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using an `iframe` or [AJAX load](http://api.jquery.com/load/)?

Comment: You might want to review http://stackoverflow.com/questions/311433/embedding-text-html-in-an-object-instead-of-an-iframe @NRohler - It appears that you can gain certain advantages (loading a local file?) that you can't with an `iframe`. I've not heard of it, but if you search, you'll find numerous questions, so it's not unheard of.

Comment: so maybe that's the question I should get answered first. What's the right way to break down HTML files into useful subgroups ? Using objects seemed to make sense to me until I ran into this CSS issue. Will iframes let you have the CSS code in the main HTML file apply to all the sub files ?

Comment: HTML is not really suited for building the page from several individual HTML files. The right way is to use a server-side language, or if one isn't available, running a script that combines the individual files into complete documents.